# $B$ is a Banach algebra which is a division algebra, then there is a unique isometric isomorphism of $B$ on to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

if $B$ is a Banach algeba which is a division algebra, then there is a unique isometric isomorphism of $B$ on to $\mathbb{C}$

I know that each element$\ x$ of $B$ is type $\lambda_x.e$ for unique scalar $\lambda_x \in \mathbb{C}$

then map $$\psi:B \to \mathbb{C}$$ such that $\psi(x)=\lambda_x$ is isometric isomorphism.

also $\sigma(x)=\{\lambda_x\}$. But how to prove uniqueness.

Hint is given that if $\psi '$ is other isometric isomorphism  , then $\psi '(x)\in \sigma(x)$.

But I have problem in proving this hint. Any suggestion?

Comment: How do we arrive that each element is a scalar multiple of the unit $e$?

Comment: @Berci if not then $x-\lambda e \ $not equal to $0$ for all scalar $\lambda  \in \mathbb{C}$. then $x-\lambda e$ is invetible for each $\lambda$. which contradict that spectrum of $x$ is non empty

Comment: Yes, indeed. $ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $a:=x-\psi'(x)e$. As an algebra isomorphism, $\psi'$ is $\Bbb C$-linear,  injective,  and maps $e$ to $1$. 
Then $\psi'(a) =\psi'(x) -\psi'(x)\cdot1=0$, thus $a= 0$ by injectivity, which is not invertible, so indeed $\psi'(x) \in\sigma(x) $.

Answer (score 3):

In fact a stronger uniqueness statement is totally trivial: If $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are isomorphisms (isometric or not) from a Banach algebra onto $\Bbb C$ then $\phi_1=\phi_2$:

Let $\psi=\phi_1\circ\phi_2^{-1}$. Then $\psi$ is a Banach-algebra *automorphism* of $\Bbb C$. Since $\psi$ is linear, $\psi(z)=az$. Since $\psi$ is injective, $a\ne0$; now $\psi(zw)=\psi(z)\psi(w)$ shows that $a=1$.