# Is Banach algebra $L^1(\mathbb T)$ under convolution a division algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, banach-algebras

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $f$ & $h$ are $L^1(\mathbb T)$ functions with $f\star h=0$ identically on $\mathbb T.$
Then can we say either $f\equiv 0$ or $h\equiv 0 ?$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ By convolution theorem, $\widehat f(n)$.$\widehat h(n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N.$

But, can we find $f,h \in L^1(\mathbb T)$ with $\widehat f$ is supported on odd integers & $\widehat h$ on even integers ?

I couldn't find anything .
Thanks in adv. for a hint .

Comment: You may consider $f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ and $g(x)=1$. In general, choose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $\sum_n |a_n|<\infty$ and then set $$f(x)=\sum_{n\text{ odd}}a_n e^{2\pi i n x}\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x)=\sum_{n\text{ even}}a_n e^{2\pi i n x}.$$

Comment: Easy example (special case of the above) - if we set $\mathbb T=[0,1]$, $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$, $h(x)=\sin (4\pi x)$, then $\int f(s)h(s-x)\ dx=0$. quick verification on Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rqmudg7azm

Comment: The similar result that I know, due to Titchmarsh:  $C([0,\infty))$ under convolution is a division algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a [complex division Banach algebra is isomorphic to the complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2743201/17929). Even if you consider the real scalars, the complexification gives the answer immediately.